# Not able to select Drop down value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, cascade

I want to cascade drop down list to each other for that I have to pass one selected values (ID) to another drop down. I am binding my drop down list using Web services and I have done it successfully but not able to cast each other. I tried like this but its selecting 0 which i have pass hard coded while creating drop down list

```
var o = { countrycode: $('#ddlCountry').val(), CompanyCode: '1000'};
```

I am using jQuery and want to pass one drop down value to another web method so its bind on basis of first drop down but I unable to selected selected drop down list value  Why ??

Jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function () {
                
                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Header.aspx/GetCountriesName",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (res) {
                        $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                            $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));

                        });
                    }
                });


                $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) {
                    BindCompanies();
                });
            });

            function BindCompanies() {
                var CompCode = $('#ddlCountry').val();
                var CountryCode = '1000';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(CompCode , CountryCode),
                    url: "Header.aspx/GetCompanies",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (res) {
                        $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                            $("#ddlCompany").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CompanyId).html(value.CompanyName));

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

DropDown:

```
<select id="ddlCountry">
    <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlCompany">
    <option value="0">--Select Company--</option>
</select>
<select id="ddlDevision">
     <option value="0">--Select Devision--</option>
</select>
```

WebMethod: `(There i want to pass selected Countrycode and Companycode)`

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<Company> Getcompanies(string Countrycode, string Companycode)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
            Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M[] initiatorslist = oClient.GetCompanies(Countrycode, Companycode);
            //almarai.giveaway.getinitiatorlist.alm_company_m[] companymlist = initiatorslist.companies;
            List<Company> companyes = new List<Company>();
            foreach (Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.ALM_COMPANY_M company in initiatorslist)
            {

                companyes.Add(new Company()
                {
                    CompanyCode = company.CompanyCode,
                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName
                });
            }
            return companyes;
        }
```

Where I am Doing Wrong Please Guide me

[Please see screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml6j2.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml6j2.png)

Comment: Can you break down your bunch of code into functions? How many times you subscribing to `$('#ddlCountry').change`?

Comment: @tym32167 ok I will break my Code into functions

Comment: I think it's fairly clear what you're trying to do but your description of it is not so clear. What does this mean: "I have done it successfully but not able to cast each other"

Comment: @Jamiec I am bale to bind 1st drop down list also second but not able to cascade each other

Comment: @Jamiec I am able to bind 1st drop down list and similarly second but not able to cascade each other and my requirement is cascade all drop down list for that i need id of 1st drop down list but i unable to get ID of first drop down list

Answer (score 0):

As a general pointer you need to make sure that you are only subscribing to the `change` event of your dropdowns exactly once. At the moment, you are subscribing to the change event for `ddlCountry` once for *every single returned item from the first ajax call*

```
$.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
       $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
       $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) { // don't do this!
```

Your code should be laid out like this (in pseudo code):

```
inside document ready:
    subscribe change on ddlCountry:
           execute function to load ddlCompany
    subscribe change on ddlCompany:
           execute function to load ddlDivision
  
    execute initial ajax call to load ddlCountry

    function for loading ddlCompany using ajax

    function for loading ddlDivision using ajax
```

The below demonstrates how to read the selected value of a dynamically added `option` when the dropdown is changed.

```js
var $country = $('#ddlCountry');
$country.on('change',function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$country.append($('<option></option>').val(1).html("First"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlCountry">
    <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Let me try as you suggested

Comment: Please check my Updated code still i am not able to get selected values

Comment: @user14304386 are you sure `JSON.stringify(CompCode , CountryCode)` is what you want? I doubt very much it is. Try looking at the result in the debugger. I don't know what `Header.aspx/GetCompanies` expects so this is pretty much impossible to answer.

Comment: Please check my updated code i have added Header.aspx/GetCompanies method

Comment: @user14304386 your method doesnt know how to take json data, and in any case you're not sending it json data. You need to work out what the data format is that Header.aspx/GetCompanies expects and send it that. This is not something I can answer in this question you need to go and read the docs on however youre creating your web method

Comment: I want to pass parameter from ASPX to code behind using JQuery I will then use this value into WebMethod to bind another drop down on basis of first drop down selected value but i am not able to Get selected value

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. Work out how to call the webmethod first using a browser or postman, and then its trivial to make the call using jQuery. But at the moment we're just guessing and cant answer your question

Comment: I am able to call web method from ASPX using j Query and also able to pass one parameter as u can see on code  (hard coded string but only thing is that Selected value is coming 0 or null Please help me on same

Comment: I have added as you suggested but now some different error i am getting Like : $country = r.fn.init [select#ddlCountry]